# Why doesn't Castiel get his wings back?

Tags: supernatural

In Supernatural, Castiel is tricked into giving up his Grace, the source of his Angelic powers, including his wings, and falls from heaven. In the process he loses those wings.

The same thing (or a very similar thing) happened to the Angel Anna earlier in the series, and though she goes for a while without wings, when she recovers her grace, she gets her wings back. But when Castiel gets his grace back, he doesn't reclaim his wings:

[image]

Why?

Comment: I can't really read intent in a picture, so is the question about why Castiel didn't get his wings back, or is the question about why his wings afterward look like they've had a few overnight benders without him?

Comment: I edited out the pictures and the `castiel` tag, because the pictures didn't really serve a purpose, and the tag is too localised to be useful (unless you want to retag all related [supernatural](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supernatural?sort=frequent) questions). Also, your assumption that Anna got her wings back - where does it come from? I don't remember that in the series.

Comment: It's about why cass doesn't get his wings back, not why they're damaged (although, that is a mystery as well)